# Nhibernate - eager fetchmode, outer join - Order clause for collection cause a second unnecessary query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, eager-loading

When I run the following code with a single query to get the 3 collections for the Product: pricelist, Materials and Colors.
And when product.PriceList access the collection, I have the data

```
ProductDTO Product = (ProductDTO)session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ProductDTO))
                .Add(Expression.IdEq(code))
                .SetFetchMode("Colors", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("PriceList", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("Materials", FetchMode.Eager)
                .UniqueResult();
```

The problem is that I need to list the collection PriceList in order by Num and I use the following code:

```
ProductDTO Product = (ProductDTO)session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ProductDTO))
                .Add(Expression.IdEq(code))
                .SetFetchMode("Colors", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("PriceList", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("Materials", FetchMode.Eager)
                .UniqueResult();
```

OR next code:

```
ProductDTO Product = (ProductDTO)session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ProductDTO))
                .Add(Expression.IdEq(code))
                .SetFetchMode("Colors", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("PriceList", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("Materials", FetchMode.Eager)
                .CreateCriteria("PriceList").AddOrder(Order.Asc("Num"))
                .UniqueResult();
```

This restriction means that when I access the collection product.PriceList FORCE a NEW QUERY for  PriceList (not with order clause) that is unnecessary.
And I occasionally get "failed lazily initialize collection role no session or session was closed"

Please if anyone can guide me about it. I like to solve in a single query and understand what happens.
I found similar post like one that use "not-found=ignore". I'm using NHIBERNATE 2.1.2

I reproduce below part of the mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="DotAR.M.Logica.DTO.ProductDTO, DotAR.M" table="products">
        <id name="Code" type="string" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="assigned" />
       </id>
       <set name="PriceList" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all">
            <key column="code" />
            <one-to-many class="DotAR.M.Logica.DTO.ProductPriceNumDTO, DotAR.M" />
       </set>

       <set name="Colors" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all">
            <key column="code" />
            <one-to-many class="DotAR.M.Logica.DTO.ProductColorDTO, DotAR.M" />
       </set>
       <set name="Materials" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all">
            <key column="code" />
            <one-to-many class="DotAR.M.Logica.DTO.ProductMaterialDTO, DotAR.M" />
       </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Every collection has a composite-id. Example ProductColor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
   <class name="DotAR.M.Logica.DTO.ProductColorDTO, DotAR.M" table="product_colors">
        <composite-id unsaved-value="any">
            <key-property name="Code" type="string" />
            <key-property name="Name" type="string" />
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="Product" column="code" class="DotAR.M.Logic.DTO.ProductDTO, DotAR.M" insert="false" update="false" />
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.CreateCriteria("PriceList").AddOrder(Order.Asc("Num"))` -> NH applies the order to `ProductDTO.Num`.

Otherwise its basicly a noop. Since PriceList is a set which has no order even sorted results from the database will get unsorted clientside. What you probably want is:

```
// using linq
var orderedPrices = Product.PriceList.Ordery(price => price.Num).ToList();
```